# Deadlock in MYSQL during SELECT and TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql-5.7, deadlock

We are regularly getting a deadlock in our application. this requires us to kill the deadlocked queries.

We are getting the following error in our logs

`"Waiting for table metadata lock   SELECT"`

this is followed by

`Waiting for table metadata lock    TRUNCATE`

so we recon this is happening as SELECT query is executing, TRUNCATE query tries to a lock and then all impending SELECT query gets in a deadlock

unfortunately, we have tried various strategies like reducing query execution time, indexing, etc. but the deadlocks are still occurring on regular basis.

I understand sqlserver has some way to set the locking priority to avoid these issues, but is there anything similar in MYSQL also?

or is there any other way to avoid it?

a sample logs is as follows:

`2835  root    ASVMPDMC0263:55346  sma_blink   Query   2943    Sending data  SELECT '2020-11-11 11:02:50.312' ,master.ClientId,master.ClientName,master.MobileNo,master.Email,master.L1,master.L2,master.L3,master.L4,master.L5,master.L6,master.L7,master.L8,master.L9,master.L10,master.LastTraded,CONCAT(IFNULL(master.ClientRank,''),'-',IFNULL(master.ClientProfile,''),'-',IFNULL(master.ClientSubProfile,'')) AS clientProfile,master.SubscriberId,1008 AS ruleId,'BUY2_PRICE_REACHED' AS shortcode,5904 AS eventinstanceId,0 as followup,2789 AS publisherId,5904 AS eventinstanceKey,3 as rulecategory,'RA_BUY2' as eventkeyfield,'1' AS ruleImpression,null AS script,null AS segment,0 AS meId,CONCAT_WS('','Buy2 price reached for : ',master.callMessage) AS EventInstanceName ,8388608 AS channelId,'2020-11-11' AS mutedate, '2020-11-11 11:02:50.312'  AS occurrenceDT,NULL AS JSONREPORT FROM sma_call_traded_clients master WHERE ( master.Leg1Type ='1'  OR  master.Leg1Type ='2' )   AND master.tipId=5904 AND master.is_qualified!='B' AND master.L1 = 'HO' INTO OUTFILE '/database/brokerserver/jaamoon_home/etl/inbox/5904_1008_11112020_110250.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 2618    root    192.168.103.176:55054   sma_blink   Query   2860    Waiting for table metadata lock TRUNCATE sma_call_track_report_leg1_dealer_comm 2839    root    ASVMPDMC0263:55374  sma_blink   Query   1528    Waiting for table metadata lock SELECT '2020-11-11 11:26:24.775' ,master.ClientId,master.ClientName,master.MobileNo,master.Email,master.L1,master.L2,master.L3,master.L4,master.L5,master.L6,master.L7,master.L8,master.L9,master.L10,master.LastTraded,CONCAT(IFNULL(master.ClientRank,''),'-',IFNULL(master.ClientProfile,''),'-',IFNULL(master.ClientSubProfile,'')) AS clientProfile,master.SubscriberId,1008 AS ruleId,'BUY2_PRICE_REACHED' AS shortcode,5893 AS eventinstanceId,0 as followup,2789 AS publisherId,5893 AS eventinstanceKey,3 as rulecategory,'RA_BUY2' as eventkeyfield,'1' AS ruleImpression,null AS script,null AS segment,0 AS meId,CONCAT_WS('','Buy2 price reached for : ',master.callMessage) AS EventInstanceName ,8388608 AS channelId,'2020-11-11' AS mutedate, '2020-11-11 11:26:24.775'  AS occurrenceDT,NULL AS JSONREPORT FROM sma_call_traded_clients master WHERE ( master.Leg1Type ='1'  OR  master.Leg1Type ='2' )   AND master.tipId=5893 AND master.is_qualified!='B' AND master.L1 = 'HO' INTO OUTFILE '/database/brokerserver/jaamoon_home/etl/inbox/5893_1008_11112020_112624.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 2795    root    10.9.162.135:58538  sma_blink   Query   0   statistics  SELECT distinct secToken INTO secToken2 FROM sma_feedcontrol_nsefno WHERE secToken=SecToken1 2834    root    ASVMPDMC0263:55344  sma_blink   Query   294 Waiting for table metadata lock SELECT '2020-11-11 11:46:58.707' ,master.ClientId,master.ClientName,master.MobileNo,master.Email,master.L1,master.L2,master.L3,master.L4,master.L5,master.L6,master.L7,master.L8,master.L9,master.L10,master.LastTraded,CONCAT(IFNULL(master.ClientRank,''),'-',IFNULL(master.ClientProfile,''),'-',IFNULL(master.ClientSubProfile,'')) AS clientProfile,master.SubscriberId,1004 AS ruleId,'ON_MANUAL_CALL_CLOSE' AS shortcode,5889 AS eventinstanceId,0 as followup,2789 AS publisherId,5889 AS eventinstanceKey,3 as rulecategory,'RC_MMC' as eventkeyfield,'1' AS ruleImpression,null AS script,null AS segment,0 AS meId,CONCAT_WS('','Manual closed : ',master.callMessage) AS EventInstanceName ,8388608 AS channelId,'2020-11-11' AS mutedate, '2020-11-11 11:46:58.707'  AS occurrenceDT,NULL AS JSONREPORT FROM sma_call_traded_clients master WHERE ( master.Leg1Type ='1'  OR  master.Leg1Type ='2' )   AND master.tipId=5889 AND master.is_qualified!='B' AND master.L1 = 'HO' INTO OUTFILE '/database/brokerserver/jaamoon_home/etl/inbox/5889_1004_11112020_114658.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 2819    root    192.168.103.176:56225   sma_blink   Query   0   executing   select * from information_schema.`PROCESSLIST `where command!='sleep' 2`

Comment: So `Select`-->`Truncate`--> `SELECT 1-n' so all rest selects would get nothing back, so the big questions why a Truncate at all

Comment: Truncate is used by a producer process to clear the table and ensure only latest data is available for processing. so, when the process starts it clears the table by truncating the data and then populate it with fresh one. however the consumer processes continue to read from the table. I know it sounds bit too much and might be having a few use cases which might sound  gaps (but are acceptable ) rather then having dirty data. The data is in excess of 500K and gets re-generated every 10min or so. Hope this gives a better perspective

Comment: @Vivek Could you from MySQL root login  SET GLOBAL innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1; let it run for an hour so we can see in your error log the frequency of your deadlocks?  At the end of the hour, SET GLOBAL innodb_print_all_deadlocks=0 to stop additional entries to your error log for the day.  If the error log is more than 100 lines, post to pastebin.com and share the link with us.

Comment: @wilson we set the parameter but did not get any issue today. As per our observations it happens nonce every 3-4 days. But when it happen it being down the house.

Comment: @VivekYou may be able to keep this active in your config every day.  Just so you are aware of the occasional deadlocks to allow corrective action.  Review your error log content every day for monitoring your instance abnormalities, please.